# 'cocos' is not recognized as an internal or external command in the my project directory

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

I am very much beginner in cocos2d-js game development, I am learning it past two days. I tried to run the my project through cocos command BUT its showing cocos command is not recognized as internal or external command. I have followed this link to create and run the project http://cocos2d-x.org/docs/manual/framework/html5/v2/cocos-console/en

My project directory is D:\Mallikarjun_Disk\cocosAndroid\cocos2d-js-v3.0\cocos2d-js-v3.0\tools\cocos2d-console\bin\Projects\MySimpleGame

I moved to this directory to run my MySimpleGame in command prompt BUT its throwing error 'cocos' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Please give suggestions what might be the problem. 
Giving me a simple steps for running project would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You've most likely:

A. Not ran `setup.py` from your installation folder.
B. Already ran it, but haven't rebooted your system yet.

(Note that you need to have previously installed Python v2.x, Ant -and possibly CMake- in order for setup and all other commands to work).

If you've already done this and still get the error, make sure in your System's Environment Variables that the path to `[your cocos2d-js install folder]\tools\cocos2d-console\bin` has been added to your `PATH`.

---

It'd also be best if you let your project and cocos2d installation folders in two separate folders with short names and no spaces, for example:

```
C:\cocos2d-js
C:\cocos2d-projects\MySimpleGame
```

Answer (score 1):

In cocos2d-x v3.2 for cpp i got same error.. it turned out
i did not run

source  /Users/your_user/.profile (so that environment variables are actually updated)
this line is generated after you run setup.py

All steps:

```
Run setup.py
Run source /Users/your_user/.profile (so that environment variables are actually updated)
Run cocos new mygame -p com.your_company.mygame -l cpp -d /directory_to_your_game
```

replace cpp with js in above command